# MacOS 10.13: Visual Studio Won't Start

Tags: macos, crash, ide

I've just downloaded and installed VS but it won't start. I don't get any errors at all, that app simply does nothing when launched (although it does load for a while). I didn't need Xcode so I didn't install it.

I am a total mac noob and have no idea how to troubleshoot this :(

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Thanks

Comment: I am having the MacOS 10.13.4. And I have installed Visual Studio Community 2017 and it works fine. And I have installed Xcode as well.

Comment: Which exact vs did you install?

Comment: Visual Studio Community 2017

Comment: Please be more specific about the problem you are facing. If you start it from Finder, does the icon appear in the Dock? Does the VS process show up in Activity Monitor? Is there anything of relevance in `/var/log/system.log`?

Comment: Also, did you check the prerequisites at https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-system-requirements-mac?